# Why is my SATA Harddrive not being detected by Windows?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, sata, storage

I recently upgraded my Windows 7 PC to windows 10 which caused all sorts of problems. I've solved most of them, but my WD10EADS-00M2B0 Western Digital Caviar 1tb 7200rpm 3.5inch harddrive is not showing up at all in Disk Management.

The PC is an HP Z420 Workstation:

Processor   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v2 @ 3.50GHz   3.50 GHz
Installed RAM   64.0 GB
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

All windows updates are installed as of the date of this post.

The drive shows up under BOOT ORDER in the BIOS settings, but it does not show up under DEVICE CONFIGURATION.

I have tried switching SATA cables and ports. I'm not sure what else to look for or try.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your drive in a separately powered unit like a USB 3.0 docking station and connect it to your computer.
When switching on the power of the docking station your drive should spin up Afterwards ir should be relatively calm and you should not hear any repetitive patterns.